# Remove list with dict in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a `pandas` which contain this code.
And yes the keys have the same name `$`. I have converted xml to json with [xmlschema](https://github.com/sissaschool/xmlschema)

```
 "SHORT_DESCR": {
                    "P": [{
                            "$": "Line 1."
                        }, {
                            "$": "line nr2"
                        }, {
                            "$": "line 3"
                        }, {
                            "$": "line 4"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Now I have striped away the list and the keys.
I dont wanna explode and normalize this json.

I have tryed `re` with

```
df['SHORT_DESCR'] = df['SHORT_DESCR'].replace([':\s+,','\[', '\]', ':\s+', ',\s+'], 
                                ['":"none","', '{"', '"}', '":"', '","'], regex=True)
```

but that didn't work.

What I have is a column in pandas thats named `SHORT_DESCR.P` and in the row "Line 1. line nr2 line 3 line 4"

sampel file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bjornjorgensen/part1/master/testfileforjson.json

Answer (score 1):

You can apply lambda on the column, for example:

```
df["SHORT_DESCR.P"] = df["SHORT_DESCR"].apply(
    lambda x: " ".join(d["$"] for d in x["P"])
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                         SHORT_DESCR                   SHORT_DESCR.P
0  {'P': [{'$': 'Line 1.'}, {'$': 'line nr2'}, {'...  Line 1. line nr2 line 3 line 4
```

---

If the column is of type string, apply `ast.literal_eval` before:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df["SHORT_DESCR"] = df["SHORT_DESCR"].apply(literal_eval)
```

---

EDIT: Using your JSON file:

```
df = pd.read_json("your_file.json")

df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"] = df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"].apply(
    lambda x: x[0]["$"] if x else ""
)

print(df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"])
```

Prints:

```
0     Se vedlegg/dokumentasjon
1                             
2                             
3                             
4                             
5                             
6                             
7                             
8                             
9                             
10                            
11                            
12                            
13                            
14                            
15                            
16                            
17                            
Name: LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P, dtype: object
```

Comment: ok, tryed it but 
df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"] = df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"].apply(
    lambda x: " ".join(d["$"] for d in x["P"])
  File "<ipython-input-191-f2ac3c8a0cdc>", line 2
    lambda x: " ".join(d["$"] for d in x["P"])
                                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: then I tryed 
from ast import literal_eval
  
df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"] = df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"].apply(literal_eval)

df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"] = df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(d["$"] for d in x["P"])) ValueError: malformed node or string: [{'$': 'Se vedlegg/dokumentasjon'}]

Comment: same error df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"] = df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(d["$"] for d in x["P"]))

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"] = df["LEFTI.SUITABILITY.P"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(d[0]["$"] for d in x["P"]))

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: uploaded 10 post of the file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bjornjorgensen/part1/master/testfileforjson.json

Comment: @BjørnJørgensen Updated my answer.

Comment: yes that that works. but not on df["COMPLEMENTARY_INFO.INFO_ADD.P"] = df["COMPLEMENTARY_INFO.INFO_ADD.P"].apply(
    lambda x: x[0]["$"] if x else ""
) it just takes the first key and del the rest.

Comment: I have post a bug to xmlschemas https://github.com/sissaschool/xmlschema/issues/242 a list with the same keys cant be right.